# Is there way to solve blank page php error?

Tags: php, contact-form

I created a contact page, however when I test it by sending an email to the website's email (which is a  gmail address) it displays a white page

here's my php code for the contact form

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST ['name'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST ['email'];
    $message = $_POST ['message'];

$mailto = "lawsafrica@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
$txt = "You have received an e-mail from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

mail($mailTo, $txt, $headers);
header ("Location: Contact.html?mailsend");


 }
```

Here's my html code (contact.html)

```
 <section class="box1">
    <h2>Contact us</h2>
    <div class="lines"></div>
   <form class="contact-form" action="contactform.php" method= "POST"> 
        <input type= "text" class= "contact-form-text" placeholder="Your name" required>
        <input type= "Email" class= "contact-form-text" placeholder="Your email"required>
        <textarea class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your message"required></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="contact-form-btn"value="Send">
    </form>
</section>

<section class= "box2">
    <h3>Didn't find what you are looking for?</h3>
    <div class="lines"></div>
    <form class="contact-form"  action="contactform.php" method= "POST" > 
            <input type= "text" name= "name" class= "contact-form-text" placeholder="Your name"required>
        <input type= "Email" name= "email" class= "contact-form-text" placeholder="Your email"required>
        <textarea class="contact-form-text" name= "message" placeholder="Type what are you looking for"required></textarea>
        <input type="submit"  name= "submit" class="contact-form-btn"value="Send">
    </form>
</section>
<section class= "box3">
    <h4>Become a contributor</h4>
    <div class="lines"></div>
    <form class="contact-form" action="uploads.php" method= "POST" enctype= "multipart/form-data"> 
        <input type= "file" class= "contact-form-text" >
        <button type="submit" class="contact-form-btn" name= "submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: can you please share your html code?

Comment: `mailto != mailTo`

Comment: Your parameters are also wrong for `mail()`

Comment: @ShivanshuGupta please check I just edited my question to inlcude my html code.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you I have corrected it and tried it again but still got the blank page error

Comment: @JohnConde Could u please let me know how to correct them ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because you forgot to provide name for submit button in `contact.html` and in `contactform.php` it will only check for post event whose name is submit `isset ($_POST['submit'])`

```
 <section class="box1">
    <h2>Contact us</h2>
    <div class="lines"></div>
   <form class="contact-form" action="contactform.php" method= "POST"> 
        <input type= "text" class= "contact-form-text" placeholder="Your name" required>
        <input type= "Email" class= "contact-form-text" placeholder="Your email"required>
        <textarea class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your message"required></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="contact-form-btn"value="Send">
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: I have followed a tutorial in youtube of mmtuts for this contact form and he put "submit" as the name and it works fine.so what's the problem then?

Comment: if you see your first section submit button, name is missing

Comment: also replace name= "submit" with name="submit"

Comment: Omg it worked! I can see in the path of website it's written emailsend :) I haven't receive it cause I have a gmail email but once I launch my website, I will forward emails sent to me to my gmail